# Best practice to handle exceptions

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, enterprise-library

I have a ASP.NET (Webforms) project, using **entity framework** and **enterprise library** for the exception handling/ logging. What is the best practice to handle exceptions when **saving** to the database.

Should I just configure enterprise library with the exception handling block to handle all exceptions. Or should I surround each **save** statement with **try/catch** and handle the exception within each catch statement. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should always handle known expected exceptions based on your application business logic, otherwise let it go and let the Enterprise Library log it.

Another rule of thumb is that if an exception handled or not, breaks your application state/flow into an unexpected state you should let it fail.

**Example:**

```
class Programs
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Print_String(null);
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", ex.Message);
        }
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
           //no no
        //}
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Print_String(string str)
    {
        if (str == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("str");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am not sure ... if I surround my database save operation (SaveChanges()) with try/catch, what kind of exceptions I should handle. The only exception that I could think of is OptimisticConcurrencyException

Comment: You have to look at the possible exceptions that can be thrown in your SaveChanges() method and that are able to be handled by your business logic, only you can determined that.

Comment: Oh my application is very simple, database schema similar to northwind database. Do you know of any good links/examples? For example, lets take the northwind database, if I save a new category what kind of exceptions should I consider to handle? Again thanks for your help :)

Comment: I recommend you do some reading on exception handling in general, but SqlExceptions will probably be the most common ones in your situation. Exception Handling Advice for ASP.NET Web Applications: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081209-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When there is a wheel, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. enterprise library is a good way to handle exception.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Page level exceptions

```
Add a Page_Error() method to your page and handle the exceptions here
```

Application level exceptoin:

```
Add your code in the global.asax event Application_Error() to manage exceptions
```